# Basic React Route with dynamic ID not rendering component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why the component `SubPage` is not rendering whenever the route path of `/sub/:_id` is visited (e.g. /sub/5f1c54257ceb10816a13d999). This is the first time I've worked with react routes. The `:_id` part should presumably accept query parameters from the URL dynamically so I cannot see why this is not working.

I can get the [/subs](https://react-tzftat.stackblitz.io/subs) page to fetch the [API](https://em-app-basic.herokuapp.com/emails-api) and render each sub on the page but just not each individual sub page.

The route is as follows near the bottom of App.js: `<Route path={"/sub/:_id"} component={SubPage} />`

Thanks for any help here. I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tzftat) for convenience, or you can see the relevant code below:

And subPage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export class SubPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sub-details-individual">
                <h1 class="std-intro">Viewing a Single Subscriber</h1>
                <div className="sub-specs">
                    <div className="sub-specs-inner">
                        id: {this.props.params._id}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {navLinks} from "./components/nav-links";
import Root from "./components/Root";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import {SubPage} from "./components/subPage";
import ShowSubs from "./components/show-subs";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      navLinks: navLinks,
      intro: "hello world",
      url: "someurl"
    }
  }

  updateURL = (newUrl) => {
    this.setState({
      url: newUrl
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Root navLinks={this.state.navLinks} intro={this.state.intro}></Root>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/subs">
            <p>subs page</p>
            {/*this.updateURL('/subs') fails presumably because it causes the rerender infinitely - but how to solve?*/}
            <ShowSubs />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <p>homepage</p>
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/sub/:_id"} component={SubPage} />
        </Switch>
      
        <p>the url: {this.state.url}</p>
      </Router>
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- `this.props.params._id` will crash since you are missing `match` before `params`

> `this.props.match.params._id`

- few `exact` props are missing, especially in the *subs* path:

> `<Route exact path="/subs">`

**Note**: the `exact` prop will be useful in the `/` route as well.